# JSP compilation fails with "The method [MethodSignature] is undefined for the type [ClassName]"

Tags: java, jsp

```
 An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /Test1.jsp
The method addURL(String, String) is undefined for the type SearchLink
6: 
7:  if(url1!=null && url1.trim().length()!=0){
8:      myfirst.SearchLink p=new myfirst.SearchLink();
9:      String result=p.addURL(url1,source1);
10:         out.println(result);
11:         System.out.println(result);
12:     }else{
```

Please let me know if you need any further details for answering the error cause.
Thanks in advance

The complete jsp coding is as below.

```
<%@ page import="myfirst.*" %>
<%

String url1=request.getParameter("url");
String source1=request.getParameter("source");

if(url1!=null && url1.trim().length()!=0){
    myfirst.SearchLink p=new myfirst.SearchLink();
    String result=p.addURL(url1,source1);
    out.println(result);
    System.out.println(result);
}else{
    System.out.println("Not a valid url");
    out.println("Not a valid url");
}
%>
```

**And this is my Java code named SearchLink  and I have compiled this version too..**

```
 package myfirst;

 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLConnection;
 import java.sql.*;
 public class SearchLink{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    //String link="http://hosted.ap.org";
}

public String checkURL(String link,String source)throws SQLException{
    Connection con=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    Statement stmtR=null;
    //link="http://www.topix.com/rss/city/ellensburgwa";
    //String source="Sample";
    if(con==null){
            SQLConnection.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.53\\SQL2005;user=sa;password=365media;DatabaseName=LN_ADWEEK");
            con=SQLConnection.getNewConnection();
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmtR=con.createStatement();
    }
    try{
        ResultSet rs;
        boolean hasRows=false;
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select url from urlbckup where url='"+link+"'");
        while(rs.next()){
            hasRows=true;
            //String mem=rs.getString(1);
            rs.close();
            return "This URL already exists in DB";
        }
        rs.close();
        if (!hasRows)
        {

        }
        return "This URL does not exist in DB";
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }finally{
        if(stmtR!=null){
            stmtR.close();
        }
        if(stmt!=null){
            stmt.close();
        }
        if(con!= null){
            con.close();
        }
    }
}


public String addURL(String link,String source)throws SQLException{
        Connection con=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        Statement stmtR=null;
        if(con==null){
                SQLConnection.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.53\\SQL2005;user=sa;password=365media;DatabaseName=LN_ADWEEK");
                con=SQLConnection.getNewConnection();
                stmt=con.createStatement();
                stmtR=con.createStatement();
    }
        try{
            PreparedStatement insertUrlStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO urlbckup VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(1, 21211);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(2, link);
            insertUrlStatement.setString(3, source);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(4, 1);
            insertUrlStatement.setInt(5, 0);
            insertUrlStatement.executeUpdate();
            insertUrlStatement.close();
            return "The URL has been added to the Database";}
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }finally{
            if(stmtR!=null){
                stmtR.close();
            }
            if(stmt!=null){
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(con!= null){
                con.close();
            }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: The problem is that `myfirst.SearchLink` does not define a method `addURL(String, String)`. You either spelled it wrong, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you please show us the `SearchLink` class, as error lies in ?

Comment: I have updated the code.... Please advise..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should redeploy your application.

In most IDEs, when you deploy web applications jsp pages can still be edited and "redeployed" on the fly onto the web container. But with classes, you need to recompile your code and redeploy your application.

Now some IDE and auto redeploy your application on save. And there are projects like [jrebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) which allow you to change classes into your application without redeploying it.

Comment: How many times has my code been perfect, and the server gives me errors about code that was fixed and I did not remember fixing it... Too many.

Comment: I was just puzzling for over half an hour why I got an error when editing a JSP in Eclipse, and adding the classes StringBuffer or StringBuilder caused the same error (more preciesly, using their constructor did). All classes in package java.lang are supposed to be automatically imported. Finally, I realized that Tomcat was still running, so pressed the red square to stop it, then selected Project -> Clean... from the menu, and the error went away.

Comment: Addition to my previous edit: then it came back. I tested using the String constructor, and that also caused an error. It's still a mystery to me; I gave up and started writing a separate Java class for what I was trying to accomplish within the JSP scriptlet.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `myfirst.SearchLink` is a fully qualified class name, the compiler is telling you that the `SearchLink` class does not define a method called `addURL` that takes two `String` arguments.

Possible causes:

- you have misspelled the name of the method
- you have forgotten to declare the method
- you have declared the method with arguments with the wrong types
- you have called the method with arguments of the wrong types.

**EDIT**

None of the above seem to apply, so my next guess is that you have neglected to compile and deploy the latest version of the `SearchLink` class to your web server.

Answer (score 1):

it means that the SearchLink class doesn't have a method with the signature addURL(String, String).